# GraphQL Dataloader vs Mongoose Populate

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, graphql

In order to perform a join-like operation, we can use both GraphQL and Mongoose to achieve that end.

Before asking any question, I would like to give the following example of Task/Activities (none of this code is tested, it is given just for the example's sake):

```
Task {
  _id,
  title,
  description,
  activities: [{ //Of Activity Type
    _id,
    title
  }]
}
```

In mongoose, we can retrieve the activities related to a task with the [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) method, with something like this:

```
const task = await TaskModel.findbyId(taskId).populate('activities');
```

Using GraphQL and Dataloader, we can have the same result with something like:

```
const DataLoader = require('dataloader');
const getActivitiesByTask = (taskId) => await ActivityModel.find({task: taskId});
const dataloaders = () => ({
    activitiesByTask: new DataLoader(getActivitiesByTask),
});
// ...
// SET The dataloader in the context
// ...

//------------------------------------------
// In another file
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        Task: (_, { id }) => await TaskModel.findbyId(id),
    },
    Task: {
        activities: (task, _, context) => context.dataloaders.activitiesByTask.load(task._id),
    },
};
```

I tried to see if there is any article that demonstrates which way is better regarding performance, resource exhaustion,...etc but I failed to find any comparison of the two methods.

Any insight would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: I have to figure they are going to be more or less the same. There are probably more important things for you to worry about.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes you are right, surely there is a lot of other aspects to care about. Regarding the previous methods, do you think specifically of any improvement or a better approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's important to note that dataloaders are not just an interface for your data models. While dataloaders are touted as a "simplified and consistent API over various remote data sources" -- their main benefit when coupled with GraphQL comes from being able to implement caching and batching within the context of a single request. This sort of functionality is important in APIs that deal with potentially redundant data (think about querying users and each user's friends -- there's a huge chance of refetching the same user multiple times).

On the other hand, mongoose's `populate` method is really just a way of aggregating multiple MongoDB requests. In that sense, comparing the two is like comparing apples and oranges.

A more fair comparison might be using `populate` as illustrated in your question as opposed to adding a resolver for `activities` along the lines of:

```
activities: (task, _, context) => Activity.find().where('id').in(task.activities)
```

Either way, the question comes down to whether you load **all the data** in the parent resolver, or let the resolvers further down do some of the work. **because resolvers are only called for fields that are included in the request, there is a potential major impact to performance between these two approaches.**

If the `activities` field is requested, both approaches will make the same number of roundtrips between the server and the database -- the difference in performance will probably be marginal. However, your request might not include the `activities` field at all. In that case, the `activities` resolver will never be called and we can save one or more database requests by creating a separate `activities` resolver and doing the work there.

**On a related note...**

From what I understand, aggregating queries in MongoDB using something like `$lookup` is generally less performant than just using `populate` (some conversation on that point can be found [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3683#issuecomment-334025713)). In the context of relational databases, however, there's additional considerations to ponder when considering the above approaches. That's because your initial fetch in the parent resolver could be done using joins, which will generally be much faster than making separate db requests. That means at the expense of making the no-activities-field queries slower, you can make the other queries significantly faster.

Comment: Lets say in a single request I would like to fetch array of tasks, where each activity field is populated. In this case, wouldnt it be better to use dataloader instead of populate? If I had 100 tasks, populate would request mongodb 100 times to fetch activities. But if I use a dataloader, it will hit the database only once. I know what you mean by your explanation on dataloaders for graphql. But I thought dataloaders could still benefit in non-graphql(express) apps, where populate(deep, with many arrays) is used heavily.

Comment: ok never mind. I did a test with `mongoose.set('debug', true)`. I thought mongoose will make unnecessary requests to database when using populate with deeply nested subdocuments. But just like dataloader the number of requests is minimal.(depth length == number of requests)